# How to enable android Honeycomb and ICS emulator access to localhost

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Am testing my application with various android sdk's - froyo, honeycomb and ICS. My app is connecting to some web server running on localhost.

When i test the app on the froyo AVD the application connects well to the web server, but when i run the app on both Honeycomb and ICS AVD, it fails to connect to the localhost?

What setting am i missing on the two AVD's

Gath

Comment: Are you connecting to 10.0.0.2?

Answer (score 0):

localhost loops on the network card on the same device (in this case, the emulator network card).

What you have to do is set your host IP (not 127.0.0.1, the other one).

Answer (score 0):

All,

I found my problem;

I noticed that i was calling network I/O on the main thread, the new android SDK's (Honeycomb/ICS - 3.0/4.0) consider this as blocking hence throws and exception. The earlier SDK's (froyo 2.2) did not check for this or maybe they were forgiving.

If you check the catlog the exception thrown is;
**android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

To reach the local web server, the IP for the emulator is 10.0.2.2.